# Mariadb reapeats queries over and over

Tags: php, laravel, apache, mariadb

I have enabled mariadb general log. When I open my web app homepage in prod. env. I have like:

```
134777 Connect  root@58 as anonymous on google
        134777 Query    use `google`
        134777 Prepare  set names 'utf8' collate 'utf8'
        134777 Execute  set names 'utf8' collate 'utf8'
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  set session sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
        134777 Execute  set session sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select * from `section_`
        134777 Execute  select * from `section_`
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `ego`.*, `hps`.`section_type_id` as `pivot_section_type_id`, `hps`.`it_id` as `pivot_it_id`, `hps`.`it_type_id` as `pivot_it_type_id`, `hps`.`order` as `pivot_order` from `ego` inner join `hps` on `ego`.`id` = `hps`.`it_id` where `hps`.`it_type_id` = ? and (`status` = ? and `publish_time` <= ?) and `hps`.`section_type_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `ego`.`deleted_at` is null order by `order` asc
        134777 Execute  select `ego`.*, `hps`.`section_type_id` as `pivot_section_type_id`, `hps`.`it_id` as `pivot_it_id`, `hps`.`it_type_id` as `pivot_it_type_id`, `hps`.`order` as `pivot_order` from `ego` inner join `hps` on `ego`.`id` = `hps`.`it_id` where `hps`.`it_type_id` = 1 and (`status` = 1 and `publish_time` <= '2018-07-30 23:46:17') and `hps`.`section_type_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and `ego`.`deleted_at` is null order by `order` asc
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `cons`.*, `hps`.`section_type_id` as `pivot_section_type_id`, `hps`.`it_id` as `pivot_it_id`, `hps`.`it_type_id` as `pivot_it_type_id`, `hps`.`order` as `pivot_order` from `cons` inner join `hps` on `cons`.`id` = `hps`.`it_id` where `hps`.`it_type_id` = ? and (`status` = ? and `publish_time` <= ?) and `hps`.`section_type_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `cons`.`deleted_at` is null order by `order` asc
        134777 Execute  select `cons`.*, `hps`.`section_type_id` as `pivot_section_type_id`, `hps`.`it_id` as `pivot_it_id`, `hps`.`it_type_id` as `pivot_it_type_id`, `hps`.`order` as `pivot_order` from `cons` inner join `hps` on `cons`.`id` = `hps`.`it_id` where `hps`.`it_type_id` = 2 and (`status` = 1 and `publish_time` <= '2018-07-30 23:46:17') and `hps`.`section_type_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and `cons`.`deleted_at` is null order by `order` asc
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `comm_mtvs`.`comment_id` as `pivot_comment_id`, `comm_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `comm_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value`, `comm_mtvs`.`id` as `pivot_id` from `mtnms` inner join `comm_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `comm_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `comm_mtvs`.`comment_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `comm_mtvs`.`comment_id` as `pivot_comment_id`, `comm_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `comm_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value`, `comm_mtvs`.`id` as `pivot_id` from `mtnms` inner join `comm_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `comm_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `comm_mtvs`.`comment_id` in (1682, 1737, 1851, 2336, 2707, 2837, 4107, 4120, 5324, 6525, 6532, 6542, 6543, 6657, 8967, 10015, 13446, 13474, 13503, 14620, 15328, 16367, 16518, 16525, 16802, 16806, 58469, 58834, 58835, 58976, 58995, 62027) and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 15 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 25 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 21 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 14 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 18 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 16 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 26 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 13 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 49 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 15 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 48 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 510 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 19 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 14 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 511 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 138 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 510 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 12 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 10 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 14 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 16 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 13 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 13 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 15 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Prepare  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = ? and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Execute  select `mtnms`.*, `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` as `pivot_goea_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` as `pivot_mtnm_id`, `goea_mtvs`.`value` as `pivot_value` from `mtnms` inner join `goea_mtvs` on `mtnms`.`id` = `goea_mtvs`.`mtnm_id` where `goea_mtvs`.`goea_id` = 17 and `mtnms`.`deleted_at` is null
        134777 Close stmt   
        134777 Quit
```

As you can see, it has repeated queries over and over. The thing is I do not have this in my local environment. In my local, the same page executes 8 queries. I have absolutely no idea why this is happening. Do you know why it is and how to make it correct? Does it have something to do with mariadb configuration? Currently It is killing my processing units easily.

I must point out that I am using php laravel. The server's is a CentOS 7. Web server is apache. Web app and db are separated over different addresses.

Comment: It's executing the same query with different parameters. Maybe there is a loop that it's looping through while executing the query. Maybe there are other people who are trying to use your site, maybe there is testing that is executing those queries. There could be any possibility, but you haven't provided any php code. Look at the rest of the line in the log, it shows you what the 'goea_mtvs.goea_id is every time it's executed and every time it's different

Comment: "I have absolutely no idea why this is happening" - welcome to Stackoverflow. The people here are happy to help when you run into problems with your code if you describe the problem and show your code. Please read the FAQ and have a look at some other questions here to see what is well received and prompts sensible and informed answers and compare this with the kind of questions which get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your localhost and production might be due to the amount of rows in the database.

Laravel lazy loads relationships by default, meaning that every time you iterate a collection of items over Eloquent and access a relationship, a new query will be executed under the hood.

```
$users = App\User::all();
// Executes once: select * from users

foreach ($users as $user) {

    foreach ($user->posts as $post) {
        // Executes for every user: select * from posts where user_id = $user->id
    }

}
```

To prevent it, You may want to take at look at eager loading relationships.

```
$users = App\User::with('posts')->all();
// Executes once: select * from users
// Executes once: select * from posts where user_id in ($users->pluck('id'))

foreach ($users as $user) {

    foreach ($user->posts as $post) {

    }

}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

@symcbean
@Chad K
This is the snippet for fetching those records:

```
$data = SectionType::with([
               'categories' => function ($q) {
                   $q->orderBy('order', 'ASC');
               },
               'contents' => function ($q) {
                   $q->with('aod')->orderBy('order', 'ASC');
               }
           ])->get();
```

And I must point out that the amount of records is the same in both environments.

@Jorge
Thank. I we are already using eager loading. No difference.